# What happens to options on a SPACs unit class post deal closure?

Tags: options, corporate-actions, adjustments

SPAC unit share classes are typically structured as following:

```
Unit = Stock + (1/5) Warrant
```

When the SPAC deal closes the ticker changes and the unit converts to stock and (1/5) of a 5 year warrant. What contract adjustment is applied to options on the Unit?

Comment: "What contract adjustment is applied to options on the Unit?" - I haven't seen any SPACs with adjustments to the warrants post-close. Note that the option is on the stock, not the unit (as the unit refers to the stock, aka trust, plus the warrant, plus any rights).

Comment: @user42108 Incorrect several of the units have options on them as well. See both SRNG and SRNGU, both have separately traded option chains

Comment: OK - seems like a misunderstanding on my part. I thought your question was about the warrants that (usually) come as part of the unit.